# iFrame event listener not working in LWC for vimeo

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe

I appreciate you looking,

For my project I need to get the pause event of vimeo iframe video.
for this I have uploaded the vimeo api script to the static resouce and  imported to the lwc page and did the following code,
but I'm not able to get the pause event.

Script

```
<script>
import VimeoScript from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/vimeoplayerv1'; // Vimeo dependency imported
export default class ClassName extends LightningElement {

  @api vimPlayer
  isVidemoInitialized = false;


  renderedCallback() {
    this.initializeLoadScript();
  }

  initializeLoadScript() {
    if(this.isVidemoInitialized == true) {
      return
    }
    this.isVidemoInitialized = true;
    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, VimeoScript)
    ]).then(() => {
          this.initializeVimeoPlayer();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading Vimeo',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
  }

  initializeVimeoPlayer() {
    let vdoIframe = this.template.querySelector(".aio-com-iframe");
    this.player = new Vimeo.Player(vdoIframe);

    this.player.on('pause', (event) => {
          console.log(event, 'pausepause.'); // This part is not working 
    });

  }
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<iframe class="aio-com-iframe" width="400" height="300" src={news.video} frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="video_iframe" >
          </iframe>
```

Any one can Please help me to fix this issue..